# Python seems to only read one item per top-level arrays

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a JSON file that I read in Python. The JSON (see below) contains two top-level items, both are arrays, containing complex structure, including other arrays at lower levels. For some reason, Python seems to only read one item from both top level arrays.

This is the JSON:

```json
{
    "deliverables": [
        {
            "name": "<uvCode>gadget1",
            "objects": [
                { "name": "handler-plate" },
                { "name": "Cone" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "<uvCode>gadget2",
            "objects": [
                { "name": "handler-plate" },
                { "name": "Cone" }
            ]
        }
    ],    
    "uvCombinations": [
        {
            "name": "st01",
            "uvMapping": [
                {
                    "objectNameContains": "handler-plate",
                    "uvLayer": "UVMap1"
                },
                {
                    "objectNameContains": "Cone",
                    "uvLayer": "UVMap1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "st02",
            "uvMapping": [
                {
                    "objectNameContains": "handler-plate",
                    "uvLayer": "UVMap3"
                },
                {
                    "objectNameContains": "Cone",
                    "uvLayer": "UVMap2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my code to read and dump the JSON file:

```python
with open("file.json") as configFile:
  configuration = json.load(configFile)
  logging.debug("CONFIG: %s", json.dumps(configuration, indent=4))
```

And this is the output:

```json
CONFIG: {
    "deliverables": [
        {
            "name": "<uvCode>gadget1",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "name": "handler-plate"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Cone"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "uvCombinations": [
        {
            "name": "st02",
            "uvMapping": [
                {
                    "objectNameContains": "handler-plate",
                    "uvLayer": "UVMap3"
                },
                {
                    "objectNameContains": "Cone",
                    "uvLayer": "UVMap2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The second item of array `deliverables` (with name `<uvCode>gadget2`) and the first item of array `uvCombination` (the one with name `st01`) is somehow missing.

I'm not a Python expert, but I think this should work like charm, and it's strange that the missing items are not even of the same index. It get even more interesting if you observe that arrays called `objects` and `uvMapping` are read properly.

What am I doing wrong?, the poor guy asks

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I suspect the file you are reading doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem. Given your JSON and your Python code, I get output JSON with everything intact. Something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Oh guys, you saved my life! As two of you reported very quickly you can't repro it and as Jordan suggested that maybe my file does not contain what I think it does, I first started ROTL, then I took a look at the files, and found that the file name was not updated... I was editing another file for hours... :D

Thanks, guys, really. If you don't say you can't repro it, I never realize this since I completely forgot about the other copy of the file.